# How to synchronize different java programs to access a common resource

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to synchronize instances of a class that access a common resource(database). This can be done by using notify and wait() but i need to know that if different java programs are using this class for creating instances than how can synchronize them.
Thank you

Comment: You can't. Synchronization can only happen in the scope of one JVM.

Comment: Perhaps you should use the database's transaction mechanism, depending on your requirements it may be enough.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sotirios Delimanolis commented - "You can't. Synchronization can only happen in the scope of one JVM."

You should therefore use some external resource to perform this synchronization. A file could be a good example:

```
try {
    // Get a file channel for the file
    File file = new File("filename");
    FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();

    // Use the file channel to create a lock on the file.
    // This method blocks until it can retrieve the lock.
    FileLock lock = channel.lock();

    // ** Your logic here **
} finally {
    // Release and close 
    lock.release();
    channel.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization will not help in case multiple processes are sharing the resource. Synchronization wait/notify model is designed to be used for multiple threads within a single process.

You need to write a logic to lock the resource explicitly. In your scenario you need to lock the database table before working on it so that other processes cannot access it at the same time.

If you are using Oracle database then you can use lock statement to a database table:

> You use the LOCK TABLE statement to lock entire database tables in a
>   specified lock mode so that you can share or deny access to them.. Row
>   share locks allow concurrent access to a table; they prevent other
>   users from locking the entire table for exclusive use. Table locks are
>   released when your transaction issues a commit or rollback.

Comment: Well i tried locking the table if a request comes for it but then all the other java programs throws exception.

Comment: @RishabhKumar That is exactly the idea, when one process is using it or locked it other processes should get an exception.